# How to list dir contents under hooks in Collabnet Subversion Edge

Tags: svn, collabnet, subversion-edge

If using like Subhooker package for hooks in Subversion (Edge), how is it possible to list the content under a directory from the WebUI?

-this restriction since myself as administrator don't have access to the production server itself...

Files on server:

```
/<reporoot>/<repo>/hooks/pre-commit.bat
/<reporoot>/<repo>/hooks/subHooker-2.2.0/etc/subHooker.properties
```

WebUI lists only like "pre-commit.bat" / post-commit.tmpl aso.

Using Subversion Edge version 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion Edge does not give a general purpose browser of the server filesystem.  Why would it?  That would be a security risk.

It does give you access to the hooks folder of a repository.  Just use the option to show the repository details, and then click on the hooks tab.  This lets you upload or edit files in the hooks folder for the repository.  It does not let you establish a browse a folder hierarchy within that structure though.

Comment: Well, complex development environment requires complex hooks. Hooks that cannot be implemented using a bat file... Simple as that. Thanks for the answer...